# Bracket relation for Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity

I can't understand the following reasoning:

[image]

It seems to me that Eqs. (3.16), (3.15), and (3.14) contradict the Lorentz transformation (3.13). It seems clear that (3.14) imply that $y$ and $x$ are changing, contradicting what (3.13) says.

Comment: What makes you think that y and x are changing? How is it clear to you?

Comment: Hi. From (3.14) or (3.16), $y'=y+vzV_{y}$, and I don't see why would $V_{y}=0$ in general.

Comment: Also, from the Poisson Bracket point of view, from (3.16) $\left[y,K_{z}\right]=zV_{y}\neq0$, so $K_{z}$ is generating a change in the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: I think 3.13 are shown for a boost in 1+1 only but then 3.14-16 are generalisations to 3+1. Without seeing the text prior it's hard to tell what author is getting at.

Comment: The text is from the article "How relativity determines the Hamiltonian description of an object in classical mechanics" by T. F. Jordan. Though the bracket relations (3.16) can be found in several places like  D. G. Currie, T. F. Jordan, and E. C. G. Sudarshan, Rev. Mod. Phys. 35, 350 (1963). It seems to be a well established identity, I just can't understand it.